# Inserting Date and Time using date and time picker in the view?IN CI

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to insert date and time in the database, I am using  a date and time picker. In the controller am dumping the results first to check whether all the fields are picked and here is my problem , it picks only the time and thus it does not insert the data. I am posting data using ajax.
Here is my view and controller respectively,

```js
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/typeahead.js/bloodhound.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/typeahead.js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/typeahead.js/typeahead.jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput-angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>



<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Send Message
</button>
<style type="text/css">
    .modal-backdrop{z-index: 1200;}
    .modal{z-index: 1201;}
    .tt-dropdown-menu{z-index: 1203; border: solid 1px #CCC; margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0; background-color: #fff; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;}
    .tt-suggestions{}
</style>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="z-index: 9999;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Send Message</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="SendSMSForm" id="SendSMSForm" action="<?php echo site_url();?>/sms/sms_form"  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sender</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p class="form-control-static"><label class="label label-primary">Inclusion</label></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="receiver" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" id="receiver" type="text" placeholder="" name="receiver" >
                            <p class="help-block">
                                <small>
                                    Enter name of person/group in address-book E.g John, Family, Workmates
                                </small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="body" rows="3"></textarea>
                                    
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#SendSMSOptions">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Options
                    </a>
                    <div id="SendSMSOptions" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Schedule" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Schedule Send</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-datepicker">
                                        <input data-provide="datepicker" name="sendscheduletime" type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                                        <input id="timepicker" data-template="modal"  name="sendscheduletime" type="text" class="form-control">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="SendSMS">Send Now</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    //we are one
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.collapse').collapse();
        $('#timepicker').timepicker({showMeridian: false, minuteStep: 15, defaultTime: 'current'});

        $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            startDate: '-3d',
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        });
        
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#SendSMS").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log($('#SendSMSForm').serializeArray())
                jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url('sms/sms_form') ?>",
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data:  $('#SendSMSForm').serializeArray(),
                        success: function(data){
                               alert(data);
                              }
                          });
                            return false;
                    });
                });

        var cities = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            prefetch: '<?php echo base_url("c_contacts/index/cities") ?>'
        });
        cities.initialize();

        

    });
</script>
```

```js
<?php defined( 'BASEPATH' ) OR die('No direct script access allowed!');

class sms extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->config->load('facebook');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->model('countries');
        $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->load->model('sms_model');
    }
        public function index() {
    }

    public function sms_form(){


        $sender = ('sender');
        $body = $this->input->post('body');
        $numberofpages = $this->input->post('numberofpages');
        $sendscheduletime = $this->input->post('sendscheduletime');
        $route = $this->input->post('route');
        $category = $this->input->post('category');
        $recepientscount = $this->input->post('recepientscount');
        $receiver = $this->input->post('receiver');
        $sumcharge = $this->input->post('sumcharge');
        $sentstatus = $this->input->post('sentstatus');

        $sms_data = array(
            'body' => $body,
            'numberofpages' => $numberofpages,
            'sender' => 'inclusion',
            'sendscheduletime' => $sendscheduletime,
            'route' => $route,
            'category' => $category,
            'recepientscount' => $recepientscount,
            'receiver' => $receiver,
            'sumcharge' => $sumcharge,
            'sentstatus' => $sentstatus,
        );
        var_dump($sms_data);die;
        $add= $this->sms_model->insert($sms_data);
        if ($add) {
         echo "<script>alert('Message Send Successfully....!!!! ');</script>";
            }
            else{
                echo "There is a problem";
            }
        // $this->load->view('modal_send_sms'); // Reloading after submit.
        // $this->redirect('outbox');
    }
}

/* End of file sms.php */
```

Comment: What you are getting with this line - `   console.log($('#SendSMSForm').serializeArray())` are you getting all the data there?

Comment: @SilentCoder yes i am

Comment: So the problem is that data not get pass to the controller ? Am I right?

Comment: @SilentCoder no its actually passing, when you look keenly in my controller i am dumping whatever that is being picked, its only the date that does not pass

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to pick both, you need to separate both fields while posting in the controller like this:

```html
<?php defined( 'BASEPATH' ) OR die('No direct script access allowed!');

class sms extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->config->load('facebook');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->model('countries');
        $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->load->model('sms_model');
    }
        public function index() {
    }

    public function sms_form(){


        $sender = ('sender');
        $body = $this->input->post('body');
        $numberofpages = $this->input->post('numberofpages');
        $sendscheduletime = '';
            if(isset($_POST['datepicker'])){
                $sendscheduletime .= $_POST['datepicker'];
            }
            if(isset($_POST['timepicker'])){
                //add a space before
                $sendscheduletime .= ' ' .$_POST['timepicker'];
            };
        $route = $this->input->post('route');
        $category = $this->input->post('category');
        $recepientscount = $this->input->post('recepientscount');
        $receiver = $this->input->post('receiver');
        $sumcharge = $this->input->post('sumcharge');
        $sentstatus = $this->input->post('sentstatus');

        $sms_data = array(
            'body' => $body,
            'numberofpages' => $numberofpages,
            'sender' => 'inclusion',
            'sendscheduletime' => $sendscheduletime,
            'route' => $route,
            'category' => $category,
            'recepientscount' => $recepientscount,
            'receiver' => $receiver,
            'sumcharge' => $sumcharge,
            'sentstatus' => $sentstatus,
        );
        var_dump($sms_data);die;
        $add= $this->sms_model->insert($sms_data);
        if ($add) {
         echo "<script>alert('Message Send Successfully....!!!! ');</script>";
            }
            else{
                echo "There is a problem";
            }
        // $this->load->view('modal_send_sms'); // Reloading after submit.
        // $this->redirect('outbox');
    }
}

/* End of file sms.php */
```

Then make sure the name inside the view are different